# Python: How to substract one datetime column values from other datetime column values

Tags: python

I need to find a way to subtract the 2 datetime column values. I tried as below,

```
from datetime import datetime

t1 = datetime.strptime('2022-07-31 23:58:30+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fz')
print('planned_event_time:', t1.time())

t2 = datetime.strptime('2022-07-31 23:58:30+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fz')
print('actual_event_time:', t2.time())

# get difference
delta = t2 - t1
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-07-31 23:58:30+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fz'
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with the format you're using to parse the dates. Here's a fix to your code:

```py
# Change '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%fz' to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'
#                          ^  ^                       ^ ^
#                          |  |                       | |
#                          +--+                       +-+
t1 = datetime.strptime('2022-07-31 23:58:30+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
print('planned_event_time:', t1.time())

t2 = datetime.strptime('2022-07-31 23:58:30+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
print('actual_event_time:', t2.time())

# get difference
delta = t2 - t1
```